# Responsive bootstrap for rails not working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to appropriately use the responsive bootstrap.css within rails? It seems to me when I create an additional experiment project (with the same html and css index code) on the side, linking only the following 2 stylesheets works fine.
**Works:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

This is where I am confused. It seems my problem  is using style link tag that loads all the css files from each page within the application.html.erb file:
**Does not work:**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

How would I make it so that it only loads 2 style sheets within the application file instead of all? I have tried installing the sass gem but has gotten me no where. Would like to know how to do this for efficiency reasons but I'm all ears if there's a better solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, are you asking how to use bootstrap and bootstrap responsive in a Rails project or how to does the asset pipeline works :-)?

I would suggest you read this first http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: ahh thanks! I guess my question is two parted. Primarily, my question is how to use bootstrap responsive within a rails project.

Comment: Do you have a 'css' directory somewhere? That is not part of a typical  Rails setup. I agree with Guy: Read through the documentation for the asset pipeline and then clarify your question as needed.

Comment: You can include the Bootstrap assets manually or try a gem like https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a gem like [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)

Or you can manually copy the Bootstrap assets into your Rails project. I'd recommend placing them in a vendor directory like /app/assets/stylesheets/vendor/.

Then make sure those files are included in your appication.css (manifest) file.

```
*= require vendor/bootstrap-responsive.css
*= require vendor/bootstrap.css
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not understanding how the asset pipeline appropriately works. There's currently a CSS rule that's making it not size correctly. I'm sure you both know how the asset pipeline works, so I won't bother explaining any further.